Is "can be read as" "potest legi" or "potest legi ut"? Or maybe something else?
So, how would you say "If Illyrian was a centum language, 'Curicum' can be read as 'northern wind'." in Latin? Would you say "Si lingua Illyrica erat 'centum' lingua, 'Curicum' potest legi 'caurus, ventus borealis'."? Or would you say "Si lingua Illyrica erat 'centum' lingua, 'Curicum' potest legi ut 'caurus, ventus borealis'."? Or something else?

I would suggest a rephrasing to work around this, as I feel that with lead to better Latin:

X videri potest significare Y.
= X can be seen to mean Y.
≈ X can be read as Y.

A combination of videtur + posse + inf. can be found in Plautus, Bacchides, 695:

Vix videtur fieri posse.

This is not exactly what I suggested, of course, but a pointer to a similar attested construction.
In general when it comes to problems like this, try to rephrase your sentence in different ways before looking for a translation.
It protects you against the worst calques.

So, how would you say "If Illyrian was a centum language, 'Curicum' can be read as 'northern wind'." in Latin?

@FlatAssembler You can replace the X and Y with anything, such as: 'Auster' videri potest significare 'ventus australis'. The point of that structure is that it is as simple as that. I understood that the question is about "can be read as"; the vocabulary and other choices in the surrounding text are best taken to a separate question if you want have specific questions about them.
